# How to use ModelForm with django-address?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm looking to use [django-address](https://pypi.org/project/django-address/) to store an Address against a Profile. Entering an address through both my webpage and the Django admin results in an Address being saved, however, the Address is not being stored against the Profile, i.e. the Profile object does not end up with an Address. How do I get the Address to be saved against the Profile model?

```
# profiles/forms.py
from django import forms
from profiles.models import Profile
from address.forms import AddressField, AddressWidget


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):    

  class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['somefieldsthatsave',
              'address',
              ]
    field_classes = {
        'address': AddressField,
    }
    widgets = {
        'address': AddressWidget,
    }
```

-

```
# profiles/models.py
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm
from address.models import AddressField


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = AddressField(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]
        permissions = (
            ('view_profile', 'View profile'),
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        assign_perm('view_profile', self.user, self)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

-

```
# profiles/views.py
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView  
from guardian.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

from profiles.models import Profile
from profiles.forms import ProfileUpdateForm


class ProfileOverview(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm
    permission_required = 'view_profile'
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How do you check if the address is properly saved?

Comment: I checked through the Address section of the admin interface and the full details appeared correct. However, in the Profile section there was no associated Address.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `ProfileUpdateForm`? In your `ProfileAdmin`, is there an `AddressInline`?

Comment: Hi Mark - I believe that the information around ProfileUpdateForm is already there? No, there is no AddressInline in ProfileAdmin - please could you explain why this is relevant? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the address as inline in your admin file.

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from address.models import Address
from profiles.models import Profile

class AddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Address

@admin.site.register(Profile)
class UserProfile(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AddressInline,)
```

Comment: Hi Mensaah, thank you for your answer - how will this help?  I get the following error message: "<class 'profiles.admin.AddressInline'>: (admin.E202) 'address.Address' has no ForeignKey to 'profiles.Profile'."

Comment: Just to confirm, can you see the profile model on your admin?